# Firebase background Push Notifications not working & not reconnecting to FCM on did become active

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the sample app delegate code line for line from the [Firebase example app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L113) but I still cannot receive push notifications in the background. If I re-launch the app I see them in the console when in the foreground.

I'm pretty sure I have everything configured within my app, and the only anomaly I can find is that when entering the background, it disconnects from FCM (apparently by design), but when I bring the app into the foreground it doesn't reconnect because the token is `nil` (it bails out on the first guard).

```
func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        return;
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
```

This is strange because when launching the app the instance token is set, so I'm not sure why it stops working.

This may not be why I'm seeing push notes in the background but I think solving this may be the start of getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: Check your application's info.plist file and enable push notification and in capability section too.

Comment: Yep all had been done. I'm pretty sure I've covered every setting, including background mode, entitlements, certs, and I followed all instructions thoroughly on their guides. Still no luck!

Comment: The callbacks for push notifications are different when in foreground and background, can you check it?

Comment: My app delegate is identical to their example and has all the correct delegate methods: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: @Sencha any success?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. When I send a data message via PyFCM and if the app is in background, I don't get any push notification.